# how to animate marginTop of a div with click

Tags: click, jquery-animate, toggle, margin

I want to animate a div with its marign-top property.Initially it set to margin-top:10%.On Click its reduce the margin-top to 5% and reveals the next div with its content(with toggle()).

```
#login
{
margin:10% auto;
......
}


$("#login").click(function()
{   
  $( "#outer_wrapper" ).toggle( "clip",300);
  $("#login").animate({marginTop:'5%'});
}
```

That works fine.But how to get back to initial "margin-top:10%" when clicked the "#login" again?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, you can do some common animation with transition properties. For example

```
.test{
   -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

And then directly set the margin top style of the element (as you are using jquery)

```
$('.test').css('margin-top','5%');
```

Then it will apply the animation automatically. This 'linear' animation can take effect on most css changes such as width, height, background color, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll just go with jQuery:

```
$("#login").click(function() {   
  if($('#login').css('margin') == '10%'){       // check if has 10% margin atm.
    $( "#outer_wrapper" ).toggle( "clip",300);  // if true => apply the 5% margin
    $("#login").animate({marginTop:'5%'});
  } else {
    // whatever you also want to do here...
    $("#login").animate({marginTop:'10%'});     // otherwise apply the 10%
  }
}
```